# Retrofit parse empty array []

Tags: android, gson, retrofit

I need to parse list of object, whith can be emply.  `{"data":[]}`
I use tamplated callback `CallBack<T>`called with

```
public static DataList {
    public List<Data> data
};

api.getData(new Callback<DataList>() {...});
```

it crashed with error:`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com...DataList`
Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model should work fine. Perhaps your server isn't returning what you think it does, or maybe its not `application/json` what it's returning?

Here's a quick demo:

Doing a GET on the url http://www.mocky.io/v2/5583c7fe2dda051e04bc699a will return the following json:

```json
{
  data: [ ]
}
```

If you run the following class, you'll see it works just fine:

```java
public class RetrofitDemo {

  interface API {

    @GET("/5583c7fe2dda051e04bc699a")
    void getDataList(Callback<DataList> cb);
  }

  static class DataList {

    List<Data> data;
  }

  static class Data {
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    API api = new RestAdapter.Builder()
        .setEndpoint("http://www.mocky.io/v2")
        .build()
        .create(API.class);

    api.getDataList(new Callback<DataList>() {

      @Override
      public void success(DataList dataList, Response response) {
        System.out.println("dataList=" + dataList);
      }

      @Override
      public void failure(RetrofitError retrofitError) {
        throw retrofitError;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: @StasShakirov, I'm not sure what you mean. Why don't you try?

Comment: void <T> getList(Callback<T> callback);

Comment: and getList(new Callback<DataList>(){...});

Comment: No, see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30929575/does-retrofit-interfaces-support-templated-callbacks

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is your java model doesn't reflect the data it's trying to deserialize to.

```
//{"data":[]} does not map to List<Data> data. 
// If the server was just returning an array only then it would work. 
// It will match to the entity below make sure your cb = Callback<MyItem>
public class MyItem {
    List<Data> data;
}
```

Comment: I did this. DataList is public static class too.