# Does retrofit interfaces support templated callbacks

Tags: gson, retrofit

I have an API the returns a standard reply for all requests that gets parsed by gson/retrofit.

```
public class ServerReply<T> {
    @Expose
    private String status;
    @Expose
    private T data;
    @Expose
    private String message;
}
```

I have an interface for Retrofit that will return a list of users inside of serverReply.

```
public interface Test {
    @POST("/Test")
    void runTest(@Body Body body, Callback<ServerReply<List<User>>> response);
}
```

I would like to get a different list of objects depending on the content of the body. Is it possible to use templating/generics to accomplish this?(see below)

```
public interface Test<T> {
    @POST("/Test")
    void runTest(@Body Body body, Callback<ServerReply<List<T>>> response);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but it's a Java limitation not a missing Retrofit feature. Due to type erasure there is no way for Retrofit to resolve what the type variable `T` actually is to pass to the deserializer without a concrete class.

Comment: Would `public interface SpecificService extends GenericService<User> { @GET("/user") User getUser(); }` work? I have some shared abstract code that I'd like to be able to use getUser but I don't mind making the service again for the specific code that uses the abstract code